# What add request.login in nestjs

Tags: typescript, passport.js, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I have passport local guard:

```
export class LocalGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    await super.logIn(context.switchToHttp().getRequest());
    return result;
  }
}
```

And I implemented guard for google auth like:

```
export class GoogleAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ){
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    // get access token from request...
    const user = // validate against google api 
    request.login(user, (err) => {});

    return true;
  }
}
```

I implemented guard with direct calls to google api to validate access token as I see that passport doesn't have something similar to just authenticate access token.
With `request.login()` `express-session` is created and stored in redis it's all fine.
I just don't understand from where this request.login() is coming?
What adds it, passport (I don't use it in this guard), nestjs or session-express.

Comment: the login function is added by `passport.initialize()`.  But there was an update in the last few days, where this was removed. (to work with nestJs you have to use version 5.0.0 or lower). See here in an old version of the file, where the login function was added: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/761a8d29d64e4afac5298462913b412a8aa82569/lib/middleware/initialize.js

Comment: But if it’s removed how to add user to request now in order to send him session?

Comment: for now: use 0.5.0. there is an open issue where the creator of passport is looking into it: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/881

Comment: So answer to my question is passport adding it even if gueard is not extending any passport class?

Comment: yes, if you call `passport.initialize()` somewhere (e.g. while bootstrapping)

Answer (score 3):

[`passport`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/) is what is adding the `login()` method to the request object. Regardless if you use it in the guard or not, the request object has still been modified by passport, so it has this `login` method. It's used for creating a session with your session store of choice. [I've got a decent write-up of the integration between Nest, passport, and how to create a session based authentication system on dev.to](https://dev.to/nestjs/setting-up-sessions-with-nestjs-passport-and-redis-210) that may help shed some light on what's going on under the hood with NestJS and passport.